# Running sudo snap on WSL2 with ubuntu18.04

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kubeflow

By following https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177729/wsl-am-i-running-version-1-or-version-2 I've verified that my WSL is version 2. Running `uname -a` outputs "Linux DESKTOP 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft"

I want to install microk8s on WSL2 so that I can use kubeflow. There seems to be many instructions on how to install microk8s by enabling `sudo snap` command by enabling `sytemD` however none of the instruction seem to work on mine.

**1. following** -> https://gist.github.com/djfdyuruiry/6720faa3f9fc59bfdf6284ee1f41f950

I got stuck on `/tmp/install-sg.sh && rm /tmp/install-sg.sh` running it outputs `Error: Too many request`

**2. follwing** -> https://wsl.dev/wsl2-microk8s/

I can't even run WSL command, when I do it outputs:

```
WSL
Wsman Shell commandLine, version 0.2.1

USAGE: wsl COMMAND [PARAMS...]

COMMANDS:
identify  - WS-Identify
enum      - WS-Enumerate
get       - WS-Get
put       - WS-Put
invoke    - WS-Invoke
xclean    - Delete all files generated by this tool set
xcred     - Create or display credential file
xcert     - Get server certificate (saved to <IPADDRESS>.crt)

PARAMS specification is specific to a COMMAND.

Output will be saved to ./response.xml. If you want to run parallel
executions in the same directory, define RTFILEPREFIX in the environment.
Doing so may significantly increase files generated.

Requires: curl, xmllint, GNU core utilities.
Optional: xsltproc for output formatting, gpg for encrypted credential.
Optional: wget as alternate for curl when not available.
```

and when I try to run `apt install -yqq fontconfig daemonize` it outputs:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run with `sudo`?